# Can't delete an object from a set

Tags: java, sorting, set, comparator, treeset

I need to delete a comment from a `Set<Commentaries>`. And it worked! But I try with the code below, it doesn't work.
After I ordered my `Set` by using a `TreeSet` with `MyComparator`

```
@RequestMapping("/user/editPage/{idContractor}")
public String goToEditPage(@PathVariable("idContractor") Integer idContractor, Model model) {

.....

Set<Commentaries> comSet = contractorsWithId.getCommentarieses();
TreeSet<Commentaries> treeComment = new TreeSet<Commentaries>(new MyComparator());
treeComment.addAll(comSet);
contractorsWithId.setCommentarieses(treeComment);

return "user/editPage";
}
```

//Below my method for delete

```
public void removeCommentaries(Commentaries commentToDelete, Contractors contractorWithID) {
    contractorWithID.getCommentarieses().remove(commentToDelete);
    contractorsService.update(contractorWithID);
}
```

Help me please! I'm new to stackoverflow and if something you don't understand I can edit my question!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What is the error, and on which set do you try to call delete? `comSet` or `treeComment`? You should create a minimal, complete and verifiable example, so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: This code doesn't delete anything. You just change set's type. Please, post code that "worked".

Comment: @Ilya I've added the code

Answer (score 0):

I have creates simple example, but it works. Please, correct me:

```
public class Main
{
   static Contractors con = new Contractors();

   static Commentaries com = new Commentaries("TROL");

   static
   {
      con.getCommentarieses().add(new Commentaries("1A"));
      con.getCommentarieses().add(new Commentaries("2B"));
      con.getCommentarieses().add(com);
      con.getCommentarieses().add(new Commentaries("3C"));
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Set<Commentaries> comSet = con.getCommentarieses();
      TreeSet<Commentaries> treeComment = new TreeSet<>((a1, a2) -> {return a1.name.compareTo(a2.name);});
      treeComment.addAll(comSet);
      con.setCommentarieses(treeComment);

      removeCommentaries(com, con);

      System.out.println(con);
   }

   public static void removeCommentaries(Commentaries commentToDelete, Contractors contractorWithID) 
   {
      contractorWithID.getCommentarieses().remove(commentToDelete);
   }
}
```

Object is removed like expected

Answer (score 0):

- while working with TreeSet make sure your Comparator gives a correct result.
- In your case `MyComparator` comparing on which field is important.
- If Comparator return 0 means two comments are same which will not be added to treeset while doing `treeComment.addAll(comSet);`
- If comment not gets added to treeset which mean you can't remove it.
- though all collections gives you return flag on remove check that. If it is false means that comment was not present in treeset.

**The problem with specific code will help.**